# Remote Validation On net core 5 web aspi not work

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-5.0

I write remote validation on Model layer in my application.

```
[Remote("IsCompanyValid","Validation")]
[DisplayName("شناسه شرکت حمل و نقل")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} الزامی می باشد.")]
[Range(1, maximum: MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "{0} می تواند بین {1} تا {2} باشد.")]      
public decimal CompanyId { get; set; }
```

and create a validation controller in Api layer of application:

```
public class ValidationController: ControllerBase
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult IsCompanyValid(decimal companyId)
        {
            return new JsonResult(false);
        }
    }
```

not work only Remote attr on model!

[ProjectImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlcue.png)

I add Method on Remote method type to POST and add [HttpPost] on controller! so not work any changed!

Comment: Can you tell me what error messages do you have?  If you added minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.